# publish two separate result directories from nextflow process

Tags: nextflow

I have a nextflow process that outputs a result folder and a log as below:

```
process test {
    label "x"

    input:
    path(somefile)

    output:
    path "test_results"
    path "test_log.log"
    path "something_for_next_process", emit: f

    shell:
    '''
    myshellcommand
    '''
}
```

And a config file to publish the results like below.

```
process
{
    withLabel : x
    {
        publishDir =
        [
            path: {"$params.outdir/"},
            pattern: "*_results",
            mode: 'copy',
            saveAs: {filename -> "${filename.split('_')[0]}/all_results/${filename.split("_")[1]}"}
        ]
    }
    withLabel : x
    {
        publishDir =
        [
            path: {"$params.outdir/"},
            pattern: "*.log",
            mode: 'copy',
            saveAs: {filename -> "${filename.split('_')[0]}/logs/${filename}"}
        ]
    }
}
```

I tried multiple combinations however, I can't get a label to publish its desired contents to two different folders. It always takes whichever is the last one in the publish config (in this case the logs). I know I can just put the publishdir options to the process in the workflow and that also works but I would like to do it through the config file. Is there a way I can get this to work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can specify the [`publishDir`](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#publishdir) directive more than once in your [nextflow.config](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/config.html#configuration-file) by supplying a list of maps, for example:

```
process {

  withLabel: 'x' {

    publishDir = [
      [
        path: { "$params.outdir/" },
        pattern: "*_results",
        mode: 'copy',
        saveAs: { fn -> "${fn.split('_')[0]}/all_results/${fn.split("_")[1]}" }
      ],
      [
        path: { "$params.outdir/" },
        pattern: "*.log",
        mode: 'copy',
        saveAs: { fn -> "${fn.split('_')[0]}/logs/${fn}" }
      ]
    ]
  }
}
```

If you don't need the `withName` or `withLabel` [process selectors](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/config.html#process-selectors), the publishDir directive can just be specified multiple times inside of your process definition, for  example:

```
process test {

    publishDir(
        path: { "$params.outdir/" },
        pattern: "*_results",
        mode: 'copy',
        saveAs: { fn -> "${fn.split('_')[0]}/all_results/${fn.split("_")[1]}" }
    )
    publishDir(
        path: { "$params.outdir/" },
        pattern: "*.log",
        mode: 'copy',
        saveAs: { fn -> "${fn.split('_')[0]}/logs/${fn}" }
    )

    ...
}
```

Comment: Ah, so the correct syntax is providing a list of maps. Have been trying for some time now except like this. Fixed my issue. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple `publishDir` directives for the same process. No need to have the `withLabel` twice. If it was in the process block, it would be like the snippet below, for example.

```
process foo {
  publishDir "$params.outdir/$sampleId/counts", pattern: "*_counts.txt"
  publishDir "$params.outdir/$sampleId/outlooks", pattern: '*_outlook.txt'
  publishDir "$params.outdir/$sampleId/", pattern: '*.fq'

  input:
```

Check an example [here](https://nextflow-io.github.io/patterns/index.html#_store_outputs_matching_a_glob_pattern).

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer! I can get it to work like the code above indeed, but when I would put the "publishDir" directives in the same label as well in the config file, it still takes the last one (logs in this example) and doesn't publish the first. Maybe it's a bug and better be submitted to git page.

Comment: I was about to reply, but Steve has already replied. Glad to know you solved your issue :)